# Tab bar disappear after storyboard segue from piechart

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uistoryboardsegue

[image]

Hi, i've a problem with a segue in the slice of `pieChart`, the segue works but its tab bar controller disappear. if i'm going to the same `ViewController` with a button on the storyboard, the tab bar appear normally.

```
Here is my code:



func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {

    guard let sliceType = entry.data as? SliceType else {
        return
    }

    switch sliceType {
    case .electricity:

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let addEleController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "electricity")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addEleController, animated: true)

    case .gas:
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let addEleController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gas")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addEleController, animated: true)
    case .water:
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let addEleController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "water")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addEleController, animated: true)
    case .phone:
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let addEleController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "phone")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addEleController, animated: true)
    case .paytv:
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let addEleController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "paytv")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addEleController, animated: true)
        addEleController.isKind(of: TabBarController.self)
    }

}
```

Comment: On which screen you are adding your piaChart ?

Comment: In the first view controller whitout tab bar controller

Comment: so it will not add tab bar under that controller as its not part of TabBar either you have to add it in one of the tab or navigation stack than and than it will show your tab on that controller